How to insert HTML to a Blazor WASM?
I am working on an e-commerce solution. The client side is a Blazor WASM .Net 6 project. I am trying to use a 3rd party payment gateway and unfortunately, their support is very poor. I am trying to progress by trial and error.
On the checkout razor page, I am trying to inject a script that displays credit card info on the page which I am getting this script as a response from the 3rd party gateway API.
Here is the sample script content and the display (https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer#):

Here is the Checkout.razor (only related parts)
    @page "/ECommerce/Checkout"
@page "/ECommerce/Checkout/{StandardDeliveryCharge:double}"

@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime
@inject ILocalStorageService _localStorage
@inject IProductService _productService
@inject IPaymentService _paymentService
@inject IOrderService _orderService
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]

@if (IsProcessing)
{
    <div style="position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:-50px;margin-left:-100px;">
        <img src="images/Spinner@1x-1.0s-200px-200px.gif" alt="waiting" />
    </div>
}
else
{
   
    <div id="iyzipay-checkout-form" class="responsive"></div>
    
    <div class="untree_co-section">
        <div class="container">
            <EditForm Model="Order.OrderHeader" OnValidSubmit="HandleCheckout">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-5 mb-md-0">
                        <h2 class="h3 mb-3 text-black">Billing Details</h2>

                        <div class="p-3 p-lg-5 border bg-white">

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label for="c_fname" class="text-black">First Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <InputText @bind-Value="Order.OrderHeader.Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="c_fname" name="c_fname"/>
                                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Order.OrderHeader.Name"></ValidationMessage>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <label for="c_address" class="text-black">Address <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <InputText @bind-Value="Order.OrderHeader.StreetAddress" type="text" class="form-control" id="c_address" name="c_address" placeholder="Street address"/>
                                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Order.OrderHeader.StreetAddress"></ValidationMessage>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group mt-3">
                                <label for="c_city" class="text-black">City <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <InputText @bind-Value="Order.OrderHeader.City" type="text" class="form-control" id="c_city" name="c_city" placeholder="City"/>
                                <ValidationMessage For="() => Order.OrderHeader.City"></ValidationMessage>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="c_state_country" class="text-black">State / Country <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <InputText @bind-Value="Order.OrderHeader.State" type="text" class="form-control" id="c_state_country" name="c_state_country"/>
                                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Order.OrderHeader.State"></ValidationMessage>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="c_postal_zip" class="text-black">Posta / Zip <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <InputText @bind-Value="Order.OrderHeader.PostalCode" type="text" class="form-control" id="c_postal_zip" name="c_postal_zip"/>
                                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Order.OrderHeader.PostalCode"></ValidationMessage>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-5">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="c_email_address" class="text-black">Email Address <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <InputText @bind-Value="Order.OrderHeader.Email" type="text" class="form-control" id="c_email_address" name="c_email_address"/>
                                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Order.OrderHeader.Email"></ValidationMessage>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="c_phone" class="text-black">Phone <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <InputText @bind-Value="Order.OrderHeader.PhoneNumber" type="text" class="form-control" id="c_phone" name="c_phone" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
                                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Order.OrderHeader.PhoneNumber"></ValidationMessage>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="row mb-5">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h2 class="h3 mb-3 text-black">Your Order</h2>
                                <div class="p-3 p-lg-5 border bg-white">
                                    <table class="table site-block-order-table mb-5">
                                        <thead>
                                        <th>Product</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        @foreach (var prod in Order.OrderDetails)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    @prod.ProductName <strong class="mx-2">x</strong> @prod.Count
                                                </td>
                                                <td>@prod.Price.ToString("c")</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }

                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-black font-weight-bold">
                                                <strong>Cart Subtotal (Shipment)</strong>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-black">@StandardDeliveryCharge.ToString("c")</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-black font-weight-bold">
                                                <strong>Order Total</strong>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-black font-weight-bold">
                                                <strong>@((Order.OrderHeader.OrderTotal + @StandardDeliveryCharge).ToString("c"))</strong>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                    <label for="dropdownMenuButton1" class="payment">Payment Method</label>

                                    <div class="col-md-12">


                                        <div class="btn-group dropend mt-2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenuButton1">
                                                @SelectedPayment
                                            </button>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark">
                                                <li>
                                                    <h5 class="dropdown-header">Available Payment Methods</h5>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" @onclick="@(() => SelectPaymentMethod("Stripe"))">Stripe Payment</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" @onclick="@(() => SelectPaymentMethod("Iyzico"))">Iyzipay Payment</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group mt-5">
                                            <button class="btn btn-black btn-lg py-3 btn-block" type="submit">Place Order</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </EditForm>
            <!-- </form> -->
        </div>
    </div>
}
@code {
        
    private string checkout;
    private string SelectedPayment { get; set; } = "Stripe";
    
    private SuccessModelDTO result = new SuccessModelDTO()
    {
        StatusCode = 0
    };



    private async Task HandleCheckout()
    {
        if(SelectedPayment == "Stripe")
        {
            await StripePayment();
        }
        else if (SelectedPayment == "Iyzico")
        {
            await IyzicoPayment(Order);
        }
        
    }

    private async Task IyzicoPayment(OrderDTO order)
    {
        try
        {
            IsProcessing = true;
            var iyzicoPaymentDto = new IyzicoPaymentDTO()
            {
                Order = Order
            };

            
            result = await _paymentService.Checkout(iyzicoPaymentDto);

            if(result.StatusCode == 200)
            {
                
                checkout = result.Data.ToString();
               
                var orderDtoSaved = await _orderService.CreateForIyzico(iyzicoPaymentDto);

                await _localStorage.SetItemAsync(SD.Local_OrderDetails, orderDtoSaved);
                
                await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("injectIyzicoScript", checkout);
            }
            
            IsProcessing = false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await _jsRuntime.ToastrError(e.Message);
        }
    }

   
}

Here is the javascript that I am trying to inject script:
function injectIyzicoScript(scriptContent) {
    const div = document.getElementById("iyzipay-checkout-form");
    if (div != null) {
        div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", scriptContent);
    } else {
        console.error('Element with id "iyzipay-checkout-form" not found.');
    }
}

But I am getting Element with id "iyzipay-checkout-form" not found. on the browser console and there is no card info page displayed.
Here is the sample script content coming from 3rd party API.
<script type="text/javascript">if (typeof iyziInit == 'undefined') {var iyziInit = {currency:"TRY",token:"dce6b28f-f7c6-45b0-af50-30473899f11f",price:1000.00,pwiPrice:1000.00,locale:"tr",baseUrl:"https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com", merchantGatewayBaseUrl:"https://sandbox-merchantgw.iyzipay.com", registerCardEnabled:true,bkmEnabled:true,bankTransferEnabled:false,bankTransferTimeLimit:{"value":5,"type":"day"},bankTransferRedirectUrl:"http://localhost:7169/OrderConfirmation",bankTransferCustomUIProps:{},campaignEnabled:false,campaignMarketingUiDisplay:null,paymentSourceName:"",plusInstallmentResponseList:null,payWithIyzicoSingleTab:false,payWithIyzicoSingleTabV2:false,payWithIyzicoOneTab:false,newDesignEnabled:false,mixPaymentEnabled:true,creditCardEnabled:true,bankTransferAccounts:[],userCards:[],fundEnabled:true,memberCheckoutOtpData:{},force3Ds:false,isSandbox:true,storeNewCardEnabled:true,paymentWithNewCardEnabled:true,enabledApmTypes:["SOFORT","IDEAL","QIWI","GIROPAY"],payWithIyzicoUsed:false,payWithIyzicoEnabled:true,payWithIyzicoCustomUI:{},buyerName:"John",buyerSurname:"Doe",merchantInfo:"",merchantName:"Sandbox Merchant Name - 3397951",cancelUrl:"",buyerProtectionEnabled:false,hide3DS:false,gsmNumber:"",email:"email@email.com",checkConsumerDetail:{},subscriptionPaymentEnabled:false,ucsEnabled:false,fingerprintEnabled:false,payWithIyzicoFirstTab:false,creditEnabled:false,payWithIyzicoLead:false,goBackUrl:"",metadata : {},createTag:function(){var iyziJSTag = document.createElement('script');iyziJSTag.setAttribute('src','https://sandbox-static.iyzipay.com/checkoutform/v2/bundle.js?v=1719940949305');document.head.appendChild(iyziJSTag);}};iyziInit.createTag();}</script>

How can I display this card script on the page?
Edit 1:
I managed to display the card on the page, here is what I have done so far.

Changed JS
function injectScript(scriptContent) {
var script = document.createElement('script');
const subject = document.querySelector("#iyzipay-checkout-form");
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.innerHTML = scriptContent;
subject.appendChild(script);
}

Added MarkupString on razor
 @((MarkupString)checkout)

Removing quotes
result = await _paymentService.Checkout(iyzicoPaymentDto);
 if(result.StatusCode == 200)
 {
     // Assuming result.Data.ToString() contains the script as a string
     checkout = result.Data.ToString();

     // Remove the beginning and end single quotes and <script> tags
     var scriptContent = checkout.Trim('\'');
     var startIndex = scriptContent.IndexOf("<script type=\"text/javascript\">") + "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".Length;
     var endIndex = scriptContent.IndexOf("</script>");
     scriptContent = scriptContent[startIndex..endIndex];

     var orderDtoSaved = await _orderService.CreateForIyzico(iyzicoPaymentDto);

     await _localStorage.SetItemAsync(SD.Local_OrderDetails, orderDtoSaved);

     // Execute the JavaScript code
     await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", scriptContent);
 }



Now the problem is after payment it does not call back to my Blazor WASM razor page since the 3rd party makes a POST request.

Edit 2:
This API action getting the response but I am not sure how to navigate to OrderConfirmation razor page on Blazor WASM?
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("PaymentCallback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PaymentCallback([FromForm] string token)
{
    var confirmationUrl = "http://localhost:7169/OrderConfirmation";
    try
    {
        // Process the payment result
        var tokenValue = token;
       
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
    }
    // Return the URL to the client
    return Ok(new { RedirectUrl = confirmationUrl });
}

Edit 3:
Adding return RedirectPermanent("http://localhost:7169/OrderConfirmation"); to the API action seems working the way I want to.

Based on your scenario and description, To integrate a third-party payment gateway script into a Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) project, ensure the target DOM element iyzipay-checkout-form exists before injecting the script. In the Blazor component Checkout.razor, after processing payment details, await a small delay to ensure DOM updates, then use IJSRuntime to invoke a JavaScript function injectIyzicoScript defined in index.html or _Host.cshtml. This JavaScript function checks if iyzipay-checkout-form exists and appends the payment gateway script retrieved from the API response.

This approach ensures the script executes correctly within the Blazor WASM application, enabling seamless integration of the third-party payment gateway

what do you mean by a small delay? Adding await Task.Delay(2000); to IyzicoPayment method?
